# Finding the specific parameter in if statement that is not true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Let's say I'm making a signup form. Now I want it to highlight them empty fields out of the four total fields. Now I could just do a bunch of if-else statements, but that would take forever.

Let's say I have the following code:

Javascript:

```
if($firstname === "" || $lastname==="" || $email ==="" && $phone === ""){
        //What goes here?
    }
```

I would like to the information inside the brackets to find which of these ($firstname, $lastname, etc) is true, and then allow it to change the css for that specific variable so I can illuminate the input field to show that it info has not been entered.

Existing Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/EVkge/

```
Click on JSFiddle to see code
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating this, simply use `addClass()` with an anonymous function:

```
$('input').addClass(function () {
    return this.value == '' ? 'empty' : '';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EVkge/2/).

Obviously change the `empty` class-name for whichever class-name you'd prefer to have; as you might have guessed the `''` following the `:` is an empty-string which would be returned if `this.value` was *not* equal to `''` (the assessment before the `?`).

As noted in the comments, this would be better if it were able to remove the added classes when the relevant `input` elements become non-empty; with that in mind then, a simple method the working of which should be obvious:

```
$('input:button').click(function () {
    $('input').each(function () {
        var that = $(this),
            val = that.val();
        if (val === '') {
            that.addClass('empty');
        } else {
            that.removeClass('empty');
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EVkge/4/).

And, secondly, a more concise approach which is equivalent to the above:

```
$('input:button').click(function () {
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this)[this.value == '' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('empty');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EVkge/3/).

This takes advantage of the fact that an object's method can be accessed using both the notation form `Object.propertyName` and `Object['propertyName']`, also using the ability to run a conditional (ternary) operator in those square-brackets to determine whether the `addClass()` or `removeClass()` methods should be used to work with the `empty` class-name supplied in the parentheses following.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [Ternary/Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Could you explain the second line. What are the empty quotes and question mark for? Sorry I'm a beginner, so I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: It's a [ternary (or conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The returned value depends on the assessment of the condition; if the condition is `true` it returns the first value `'empty'`, if it's `false` it returns the empty string `''`.

Comment: @David - I think you need to remove the class when appropriate too. I entered values in two of the four fields and clicked the submit button, and the two empty fields were highlighted as they should be. I then I entered one of them and clicked the submit button again, and both fields remained highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the fields and check each one if it's empty add a class to it as said above.

```
$('input:button').click(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function (indx) {
        var $currentField = $(this);
        if( $currentField.val() == '' ) {
            $currentField.addClass('empty');
        } else {
            $currentField.removeClass('empty');
        }
    });
});
```

I also added some extra functionality for you in this :
http://jsfiddle.net/jeffpowrs/Wzj8M/1/